# Overflow hidden is not working with absolute element in safari

Tags: html, css, safari, overflow

[image]

```css
.services {
     margin: 0 0 40px 0;
    }
    .services ul {
     list-style: none;
    }
    .services ul > li {
     float: left;
     width: 168px;
     text-align: center;
    }
    .services ul > li + li {
     margin-left: 24px;
    }
    .services ul > li .thumb {
     border: 2px solid #b9b9b9;
     border-radius: 50%;
     -moz-border-radius: 50%
     -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
     overflow: hidden;
     position: relative;
     margin: 0 0 14px 0;
    }
    .services ul > li .thumb img {
     display: block;
     border-radius: 50%;
     -moz-border-radius: 50%;
     -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
     max-width: 100%;
     height: auto;
    }
    .services ul > li .thumb span {
     position: absolute;
     background: #95bd0d;
     font-size: 14px;
     line-height: 20px;
     width: 100%;
     padding: 8px 10px;
     bottom: 0px;
     left: 0px;
     color: #fff;
    }
```

```html
<div class="services">
    <div class="container">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <div class="thumb"> <img src="http://182.73.133.220/ateet/image-3.jpg" height="168" width="168" alt="" > <span>FAKTEN</span> </div>
                <h4>Spirovent Superior - Vakuumentgaser</h4>
                <a href="#">lesen Sie mehr</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="thumb"> <img src="http://182.73.133.220/ateet/image-4.jpg" height="168" width="168" alt="" > </div>
                <h4>Spirovent Superior - Vakuumentgaser</h4>
                <a href="#">lesen Sie mehr</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thumb div overflow:hidden is not working with absolute element in safari.
As well as it won't work with thumb image also, i have also rounded the image tag with border-radius.

Word **FAKTEN** should be hidden as left image. Below is the code. Please suggest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a documented [bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=98538)

The best workaround is to add to the `.thumb` rule the following

```
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
-webkit-mask-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle, white 100%, black 100%);
```

---

```css
.services {
     margin: 0 0 40px 0;
    }
    .services ul {
     list-style: none;
    }
    .services ul > li {
     float: left;
     width: 168px;
     text-align: center;
    }
    .services ul > li + li {
     margin-left: 24px;
    }
    .services ul > li .thumb {
     border: 2px solid #b9b9b9;
     border-radius: 50%;
     -moz-border-radius: 50%
     -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
     overflow: hidden;
     position: relative;
     margin: 0 0 14px 0;
      /*fix safari border-radius and overflow hidden problem*/
      -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
      -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle, white 100%, black 100%);
    }
    .services ul > li .thumb img {
     display: block;
     border-radius: 50%;
     -moz-border-radius: 50%;
     -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
     max-width: 100%;
     height: auto;
    }
    .services ul > li .thumb span {
     position: absolute;
     background: #95bd0d;
     font-size: 14px;
     line-height: 20px;
     width: 100%;
     padding: 8px 10px;
     bottom: 0px;
     left: 0px;
     color: #fff;
    }
```

```html
<div class="services">
    <div class="container">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <div class="thumb"> <img src="http://182.73.133.220/ateet/image-3.jpg" height="168" width="168" alt="" > <span>FAKTEN</span> </div>
                <h4>Spirovent Superior - Vakuumentgaser</h4>
                <a href="#">lesen Sie mehr</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="thumb"> <img src="http://182.73.133.220/ateet/image-4.jpg" height="168" width="168" alt="" > </div>
                <h4>Spirovent Superior - Vakuumentgaser</h4>
                <a href="#">lesen Sie mehr</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Petrioli :)

Answer (score 4):

Actually it is suggested in the bug ticket to add the following to the element with overflow: hidden;

```
position:relative; 
z-index:0;
```